# Image is not added via add form but update

Tags: php, image, laravel-5

In my project I want to add images to a database.

Everything was working fine.

Now when I add a new product and choose an image for it the image is not saved to the database.

But update function can add image.

my add function,

```
  $books=Request::all();
        $book= new Book;
        $book->title=$books['title'];
        $book->author= $request->author;
        $book->publisher= $request->publisher;
        $book->year= $request->year;
        $book->price= $request->price;    

        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $image=$request->file('image');
            $filename=time() . '.' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location=public_path('images/' .$filename);
            Image::make($image)->resize(200,100)->save($location);
            $book->image=$filename;    
        }

        $book->save();
```

update method is,

```
 public function update($id, Requests\BookRequest $request){
        $book= Book::findorfail ($id);
        $book->title= $request->title;
        $book->author= $request->author;
        $book->publisher= $request->publisher;
        $book->year= $request->year;
        $book->price= $request->price;
        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $image=$request->file('image');
            $filename=time() . '.' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location=public_path('images/' .$filename);
            Image::make($image)->resize(200,100)->save($location);
            $book->image=$filename;    
        }
        $book->update();
```

add.blade.php

---

```
@extends('pages.app')
@section('content')

<h1>Add Books</h1>
 </hr>
     {{--{!! Form::open(['url'=>'books/add','files'=>true])!!}--}}
{!! Form::model(['method'=>'POST','action'=>['BooksController@store'],'files'=>true]) !!}
     <div class="form-group">

         {!! Form::label ('title','Title') !!}
         {!! Form::text('title',null,['class'=>'form-control'])  !!}

     </div>
     <div class="form-group">

         {!! Form::label ('author','Author') !!}
         {!! Form::text('author',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

     </div>
 <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('publisher', 'Publisher') !!}
     {!! Form::text('publisher',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
 </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         {!! Form::label('year', 'Publishing Year') !!}
         {{ Form::selectRange('year', 1950, 2050,2016, ['class' => 'field']) }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         {!! Form::label ('image','Icon') !!}
         {!! Form::file ('image') !!}

     </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div >
        <img src="" align="middle" height="136" width="144" >
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">

         {!! Form::label ('price','Price') !!}
         {!! Form::text('price',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
     </div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Add',['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-lg' ]) !!}
</div>

@if($errors->any())
<ul class="alert alert-danger">

    @foreach($errors->all()as $error)
        <li>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
</ul>

@endif
@stop
```

My edit view is:

```
@extends('pages.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>Edit Book's Details</h1>
    </hr>
    {!! Form::model($book, ['method'=>'PATCH','action'=>['BooksController@update',$book->id],'files'=>true])!!}
    <div class="form-group">

        {!! Form::label ('title','Title') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title',null,['class'=>'form-control'])  !!}

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">    

        {!! Form::label ('author','Author') !!}
        {!! Form::text('author',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('publisher', 'Publisher') !!}
        {!! Form::text('publisher',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('year', 'Publishing Year') !!}
        {{ Form::selectRange('year', 1950, 2050,$book->year,['class' => 'field']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label ('image','Icon') !!}
        {!! Form::file ('image') !!}

    </div>    

    <div class="form-group">

        {!! Form::label ('price','Price') !!}
        {!! Form::text('price',$book->price,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}    
    </div>    

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Update',['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-lg' ]) !!}    
    </div>    

    {!! Form::close() !!}
    @if($errors->any())
        <ul class="alert alert-danger">

            @foreach($errors->all()as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>

    @endif    
@stop
```

This is the edit.blade.php.

Comment: Paste your view code also. Let's see your two forms.

Comment: What's your function name and arguments while you're trying to adding ? If it's something like `function store(Request $request)` then problem is not in code, somewhere else.

Comment: public function store(Requests\BookRequest $request)

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code then. You can debug more for file size issue and others.

Comment: each time I chose the same image for store function and update function :/

Comment: You said "Everything was working fine". Did you change anything and it stopped working? If not, are you sure you have a problem? Try to upload a new image( even in a new directory if that helps you) and be sure that update and save works, try to isolate those two functions.

Comment: I added a search box in my add.blade.php. I have deleted the search bar but still no solution :\